# Basic string variable substitution in docker-compose files (3.8)

Tags: docker-compose, yaml

Take my example of two services:

```
services:
nginx:
    ports:
        - 443:443
    volumes:
        - "CONFIG_DIRECTORY/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
        - "CONFIG_DIRECTORY/certs:/etc/ssl/certs"

web:
    command: ["node", "index.js"]
    volumes:
        - "CONFIG_DIRECTORY/certs:/var/client/config/ssl/certs"
        - "CONFIG_DIRECTORY/process:/var/client/process"
```

I'd really like to be able to substitute a string such as `/home/garnettm/development/config` directly into the indicated CONFIG_DIRECTORY locations in the above strings.

Is there any way to do this other than the many currently available environment variable substitution process options?

A .env file for example would allow you to do this using an already defined variable and the `$VARIABLE` syntax.

Comment: Beyond an environment variable `$CONFIG_DIRECTORY` or the directory containing the Compose file `.`, what sort of option are you looking for?

Comment: I would simply like to be able to declare a reusable string somewhere in the file that I can insert into other defined variables throughout the .yml file. This would simply reduce the amount of human error that can go into the replacement of such a string in the case of editing the file via a CLI tool or something basic that doesn't have replace all functionality. 

I don't think I need to tout the benefits of having a "variable" type within files as this is simple value reusability stuff 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only form of string interpolation Compose supports at all is [environment variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution).  This uses shell-style `$VARIABLE` syntax, with very limited options for if the variable isn't set, `${VARIABLE:-default value}` or `${VARIABLE:?error message}`.

There is no way to declare these variables in the Compose file itself.  Compose does support putting variable values in a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with-an-env-file), so they don't necessarily need to be set as actual environment variables.  You do not need to mention this file in a Compose `env_file:` directive, Compose reads it on its own to set environment variables to do these substitutions.

```
# .env
CONFIG_DIRECTORY=/home/garnettm/development/config
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
volumes:
  - "$CONFIG_DIRECTORY/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

For this specific setting, on the left-hand side of `volumes:` and other places that refer to host directories, relative paths are interpreted relative to the location of the Compose file (the first one, if you have multiple `docker-compose -f` options).  A very common setup is to put all of the state and source code in the same directory tree, and to put the `docker-compose.yml` file at the root of that tree.  In that case the relative directory `.` will almost always be right

```yaml
volumes:
  - "./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

[YAML anchors](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#692-node-anchors) are occasionally used to provide common blocks of settings, but you can't do string interpolation using anchors, only supply an entire YAML scalar node.  They won't be helpful here.